# make a phone call from Unity in iOS C#

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I want to make a call from Unity 3D variable number, in iOS.

I'm trying code a C# Application: `OpenURL(+5950972345678);` But it donsn't work in the new iOS.

There is no plugin ready to make it simple and objective. could someone help me with this and provide the code, so that in the future this is practical for anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Since Unity accepts some URI schemes, you can use the following for example to call a phone number:

```
Application.OpenURL( "tel://+5950972345678" )
```

Comment: gracias tks, yes but this no longer works for me :(